# Почему не растягивается меню при 100vh?

Tags: html, css

[image: скрин с менюшкой]

```
@media (max-width: 767px)
.menu
    position: fixed
    display: flex
    flex-direction: column
    border: none
    top: 0
    right: 0
    width: 50%
    height: 100vh
    padding: 20px 15px
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .8)
```

Comment: Проблема не воспроизводится, когда я применяю этот стиль к написанному от балды диву, я получаю высоту даже больше чем 100vh из-за паддинга. Приведите [mcve], который продемонстрирует возникающее у вас поведение

Comment: Ну и перепроверьте, применяются ли у вас мобильные стили вообще, не забыли ли вы мета-тег viewport и всё такое

Comment: Возможно ви ограничили высоту родительскому div данного меню. Сложно судить, без нормально загруженого html css данной формы.